# Code works fine on jsfiddle but doesn´t work on local host

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I´ve been adapting some jsfiddle files that I found, so that the result fits to my needs.
It happens that, my code works fine on jsfiddle but doesn´t work on my localhost (used python to start an HTTPServer). More specifically the HTML file only gets the number 100 that is in the div.
I´m only copying the files to my computer, it´s anything I need to add/change more?
I´m new on coding, I apreciate any help.

The link for jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sgfcusk4/

The HTML file:

```
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
  <p><span id="value">100</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript File:

```
var margins = {
    top: 12,
    left: 55,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 24
  },
  legendPanel = {
    width: 180
  },
  width = 500 - margins.left - margins.right - legendPanel.width,
  height = 100 - margins.top - margins.bottom,
  dataset = [{
    data: [{
      month: 'Portugal',
      count: 60
    }, {
      month: 'Espanha',
      count: 40
    }],
    name: 'Diesel'
  }, {
    data: [{
      month: 'Portugal',
      count: 35
    }, {
      month: 'Espanha',
      count: 50
    }],
    name: 'Petrol'
  }, {
    data: [{
      month: 'Portugal',
      count: 5
    }, {
      month: 'Espanha',
      count: 10
    }],
    name: 'Alternative'
  }],
  series = dataset.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }),
  dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
    return d.data.map(function(o, i) {
      // Structure it so that your numeric
      // axis (the stacked amount) is y
      return {
        y: o.count,
        x: o.month
      };
    });
  }),
  stack = d3.layout.stack();

stack(dataset);

var dataset = dataset.map(function(group) {
    return group.map(function(d) {
      // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
      return {
        x: d.y,
        y: d.x,
        x0: d.y0
      };
    });
  }),
  svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right + legendPanel.width)
  .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')'),
  xMax = d3.max(dataset, function(group) {
    return d3.max(group, function(d) {
      return d.x + d.x0;
    });
  }),
  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, xMax])
  .range([0, width]),
  months = dataset[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  }),
  _ = console.log(months),
  yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(months)
  .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient('bottom'),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient('left'),
  colours = d3.scale.category10(),
  groups = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colours(i);
  }),
  rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.x0);
  })
  .attr('y', function(d, i) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return yScale.rangeBand();
  })
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.x);
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x')) / 2 + width / 2;
    var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;

    d3.select('#tooltip')
      .style('left', xPos + 'px')
      .style('top', yPos + 'px')
      .select('#value')
      .text(d.x);

    d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
  })

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis')
  .call(yAxis);
/* Rectangulo amarelo a volta dos tipos de combustivel
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('fill', 'yellow')
    .attr('width', 160)
    .attr('height', 30 * dataset.length)
    .attr('x', width + margins.left)
    .attr('y', 0);
*/

//Texto do lado direito
series.forEach(function(s, i) {
  svg.append('text')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .attr('x', width + margins.left + 8)
    .attr('y', i * 24 + 24)
    .text(s);

  //Barras do lado direito       
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('fill', colours(i))
    .attr('width', 60)
    .attr('height', 20)
    .attr('x', width + margins.left + 90)
    .attr('y', i * 24 + 6);
});
```

And the css file:

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

The only thing I did was copying the content of the files to new files on my computer and named "sketch.html", "sketch.css" and "sketch.js".

When I open the HTML on localhost the only thing I see is the number "100". It doesn´t show any error message.

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the entire html-file that you are using to import the css and javascript into, then people would be able to see what you are doing wrong. It seems like you are doing the <link> or the <script> references incorrectly.

Comment: Did you notice that the fiddle includes D3.js? You will have to download D3 yourself and reference it in your local code since the reference to D3.js is not visible on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the css and javascript files in your html file.

The css belongs in a `link` element: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="sketch.css" />`

And js in a `script` tag: `<script src="sketch.js"></script>`

Basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sketch.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <p><span id="value">100</span></p>
    </div>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the header in the HTML file add
 `<link href="sketch.css" type="stylesheet">` and just before the closing body tag add `<script src="sketch.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the contents leaves out connecting the HTML to the JS and CSS. You need to tell it to include those files, it doesn't just happen.

Link to your css in the `<head>` part of your HTML like so (assuming all files are in the same folder):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sketch.css">
```

And add this at the end of your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
```